# Google play store not working when default install location is SD card

Tags: google-play-store

I have a non-rooted Android 5.0 device. The Android installation of my phone provides an option to set the default storage location (analogous to `adb shell pm set-install-location 2`, I think).

After changing the install location, and moving the existing data files to the SD card, the already installed apps are working okay so far. I can install apps from downloaded apk files too, which goes directly to the SD card).

However I can't install any new app or update existing ones via the Google Play store. It simply throws an error stating that the app could not be installed / updated with the error code 963.

I have tried clearing cache, Google play data and resetting Google play to factory state. But the problem persists. How should I proceed next?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions mentioned here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-one-m8/help/getting-error-code-963-907-play-store-t3119007?

Comment: Unmounting the SD card was not an option, since it was being used as the default storage. However the problem with the Play Store seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed. I don't know what caused it to fix itself, but here is the list of what I tried -

- Clear application data of *Google Play Services* and *Google Services Framework*.
- Clear application data of *Google Play Store*
- Uninstall updates of *Google Play Store*
- Remove the Google Account from the device and then adding it again.

After Google Play Store is now installing and updating apps on the SD card without any fuss.